# Debugging Step Into, Over, Out within VB6 IDE closes the class window

Tags: debugging, vb6

I am experiencing very strange behavior within VB6 IDE whenever the break point hits(Step Into, Out, Over), the class is closed and makes it impossible to debug. Then within window-Cascade i can re-open the class but again when break point hits, the class is closed. Can anyone help please.

Comment: Does some component send windows messages to your application?

Comment: @ThomasWeller.  I am not sure to be honest as this is a legacy application with huge amount of code.

Comment: another year, and mods will migrate this to retro computing SE. retry on a clean installation of windows 95.

Comment: ok seriously. do you have the latest service pack, I think that would have to be VB6 SP6, and on which OS are you? all add-ins disabled?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved this issue and problem was within Display settings within windows 10. Basically if I apply vertical settings by placing both screen vertically 2nd on top of first then this issue happens,if i apply horizontal settings then this issue does not happen.

problematic settings with vb[image]

[image]
settings that does solves debugging issue. VB is so weird and old cannot cope with display settings

Answer (score 0):

Step execution does sometimes behave that way. The reason is that VB is event driven and when an event occurs, then the code behind that event will run, and your code that you are stepping through might NOT be the code that gets run, so things change and code runs while your PAUSED code is still on hold.

When I encounter that I overcome it by using debug.print to send my monitored variables' current values to the OUTPUT window, or if you need more elaborate capability, write a sub that sends the data to a local text file and then invoke that sub as needed, passing into the variables ( and labels ) that you want displayed.

Once debug.print or a logging routine is in place then run the code WITHOUT pauses or breaks.  The debugging output will tell you what is happening, in what order etc, so no need to stop the code or risk altering the order of execution.

Be sure to include lots of 'context' data such as :   'Entering SUB_XYZ, Param values are  A, B, C...  NOW at line 99 in SUB XYZ....    NOW in TRUE side of IF TEST # 1....

Include time stamps on all outputs.

Put your tracing logic only around the suspected problem area, expand from there only as needed.

It's a pain, but it works.

Comment: Note, VB.Net has built in code tracing as do some other languages.  Look there for ideas...   g'luck.